# How to access for loop variables outside for loop?

Tags: java, android

The values of appName and appVersion from `PackageInfo` list data is correctly being achieved but I want to match the Package Info data with database data.

**Problem faced**:
If I match db data to Package Info data inside for loop then loop is running infinitely and if I get the Package info data outside the loop then Package info is showing only one value.

So how to get all the PackageInfo data outside the for loop so it can be matched outside the loop?

**Code snippet**:

```
    Cursor cursor = dbHandler.getDeviceApkData();
    String dbName = null;
    String dbVersion = null;
        if (cursor.getCount() !=0) {

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                dbName = cursor.getString(1);
                dbVersion = cursor.getString(2);
           } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
List<PackageInfo> pInfo=getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    String appNameInfo = null;
    String versionInfo = null;
        for (PackageInfo packageInfo : pInfo) {
        appNameInfo = (String) getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(packageInfo.applicationInfo);
        versionInfo = packageInfo.versionName;

    }

if (dbName.equals(appNameInfo) && dbVersion.equals(versionInfo)) {
// do something here
}
else{
// do something here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to divide your code to multiple methods where each method do only one specific job.

**First**, move the following to get the `appNameInfo` and `versionInfo` to a method:

```
List<PackageInfo> pInfo=getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
String appNameInfo = null;
String versionInfo = null;
for (PackageInfo packageInfo : pInfo) {
   appNameInfo = (String) getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(packageInfo.applicationInfo);
   versionInfo = packageInfo.versionName;
}
```

We can see that your code is producing two values: `appNameInfo` and `versionInfo` which are a pair. So, we can use **Pair**. We also need to make a list of Pair for each packageInfo. We can achieve it by making the following method:

```
private List<Pair<String, String>> getPackageInfos() {
  List<Pair<String, String>> pairs = new ArrayList<>();

  List<PackageInfo> pInfo=getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);

  for (PackageInfo packageInfo : pInfo) {
     String appNameInfo = (String) getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(packageInfo.applicationInfo);
     String versionInfo = packageInfo.versionName;
     pairs.add(new Pair<>(appNameInfo, versionInfo));
  }

  return pairs;
}
```

**Second**, you need to make the database query code creating a list of data. So, you need to change the following code:

```
Cursor cursor = dbHandler.getDeviceApkData();
String dbName = null;
String dbVersion = null;
    if (cursor.getCount() !=0) {

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
            dbName = cursor.getString(1);
            dbVersion = cursor.getString(2);
       } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

to something like this:

```
List<Pair<String, String>> dbNameVersions = new ArrayList<>();
Cursor cursor = dbHandler.getDeviceApkData();
String dbName = null;
String dbVersion = null;
    if (cursor.getCount() !=0) {

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
            dbName = cursor.getString(1);
            dbVersion = cursor.getString(2);
            dbNameVersions.add(new Pair<>(dbName, dbVersion));
       } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

we also use Pair with this:

```
List<Pair<String, String>> dbNameVersions = new ArrayList<>();
```

so we can compare the data with the package info data.

**Third**, we can do something based on the `dbNameVersions` and `getPackageInfos` by checking if there is matching dbName and dbVersion in package info, with something like this:

```
packageInfos.contains(dbNameVersion)
```

This is the complete code (I haven't this this):

```
private List<Pair<String, String>> getPackageInfos() {
  List<Pair<String, String>> pairs = new ArrayList<>();

  List<PackageInfo> pInfo=getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);

  for (PackageInfo packageInfo : pInfo) {
     String appNameInfo = (String) getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(packageInfo.applicationInfo);
     String versionInfo = packageInfo.versionName;
     pairs.add(new Pair<>(appNameInfo, versionInfo));
  }

  return pairs;
}

private void checkData() {
  List<Pair<String, String>> dbNameVersions = new ArrayList<>();
  Cursor cursor = dbHandler.getDeviceApkData();
  String dbName = null;
  String dbVersion = null;

  if (cursor.getCount() !=0) {

     if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            dbName = cursor.getString(1);
            dbVersion = cursor.getString(2);
            dbNameVersions.add(new Pair<>(dbName, dbVersion));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
     }
  }

  List<Pair<String, String>> packageInfos = getPackageInfos();

  for(Pair<String,String> dbNameVersion: dbNameVersions) {
    if(packageInfos.contains(dbNameVersion)) {
      // found matching dbName and dbVersion in packageInfo.
      // do something
    } else {
      // do something when not found.
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible if we move the for loop into the while loop?

```
 Cursor cursor = dbHandler.getDeviceApkData();
    String dbName = null;
    String dbVersion = null;
    if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                dbName = cursor.getString(1);
                dbVersion = cursor.getString(2);

                List<PackageInfo> pInfo = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
                String appNameInfo = null;
                String versionInfo = null;
                for (PackageInfo packageInfo : pInfo) {
                    appNameInfo = (String) getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(packageInfo.applicationInfo);
                    versionInfo = packageInfo.versionName;

                    if (dbName.equals(appNameInfo) && dbVersion.equals(versionInfo)) {
                    // do something here
                    } else {
                        // do something here
                    }
                }

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
```